# How to make ingredients match a recipe from inputs to Firebase Real Time Database from Android Studios

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android device that connects with Firebase. The initial idea is to create an app that uses a barcode scanner to input ingredients into a database and for that database then to recognise the ingredients entered and find a matching meal idea from that. So far I have managed to connect a working Barcode-Scanner but I am not sure of how to do the next stage (matching meal idea using real time firebase database).

I have made classes such as:

```
BarcodeFragment
FirebaseDatabaseHelper
Ingredient
IngredientDetailsActivity
ListActivity
ScannerActivity
ManualActivity
MealActivity
ProfileActivity
RecyclerView_Config
```

And imported a ZXing barcode scanner module.

This is a very basic design of how I think the Real Time Database on Firebase would work but not sure.

```
barcode-reader-master-134b4

ingredients
1
insertIngredient: 
"Mince"
2
insertIngredient: 
"Onion"
3
insertIngredient: 
"Puree"
4
insertIngredient: 
"Tomatoes"
5
insertIngredient: 
"Garlic"


recipe
1
insertRecipe: 
"Bolognese"


ingredientIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not how it works at all. I highly suggest you go look at the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write